# Search inside JSON with Elastic

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have an index/type in ES which has the following type of records:

```
body    "{\"Status\":\"0\",\"Time\":\"2017-10-3 16:39:58.591\"}"
type    "xxxx"
source  "11.2.21.0"
```

The body field is a JSON.So I want to search for example the records that have in their JSON body `Status:0`.
Query should look something like this(it doesn't work):

```
GET <host>:<port>/index/type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "body" : "Status:0"
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the analyser settings of your index.

For the JSON pattern you presented you will need to have a char_filter and a tokenizer which remove the JSON elements and then tokenize according to your needs.

Your analyser should contain a tokenizer and a char_filter like these ones here:

```
{
  "tokenizer" : {
    "type": "pattern",
    "pattern": ","
  },
  "char_filter" : [ {
    "type" : "mapping",
    "mappings" : [ "{ => ", "} => ", "\" => " ]
  } ],
  "text" : [ "{\"Status\":\"0\",\"Time\":\"2017-10-3 16:39:58.591\"}" ]
}
```

**Explanation**: the char_filter will remove the characters: `{ } "`. The tokenizer will tokenize by the comma.

These can be tested using the Analyze API. If you execute the above JSON against this API you will get these tokens:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "Status:0",
    "start_offset" : 2,
    "end_offset" : 13,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "Time:2017-10-3 16:39:58.591",
    "start_offset" : 15,
    "end_offset" : 46,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

The first token (`"Status:0"`) which is retrieved by the Analyze API is the one you were using in your search.